# exception while deleting cell

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

i am trying to delete a cell from my table view but it's displaying exception:

```
 Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[RootViewController aBook]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x3d217a0'
```

here is my code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
    {  
        NSLog(@"handover values to object");
        Book *aBook = [appDelegate.books objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        NSLog(@"removing");
        [[self aBook] removeObjectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
        NSLog(@"deleting row");
        //  Animate deletion
        NSArray *indexPaths = [NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath];
        [[self tableView] deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths
                                withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }
```

control displays exception at 8th line after printing "removing" word. also giving warning that "root view controller not responding to aBook" 
help!!

Answer (score 1):

perhaps you mean

```
[aBook removeObjectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
```

Answer (score 1):

Why are you calling [self aBook]? It's local object! Try [aBook removeObjectAtIndex:  ]

Comment: still its giving same exception when i used aBook removeObjectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

Answer (score 1):

The runtime already gives you a very good explanation of what's wrong: You are sending a `aBook` message to an object of type `RootViewController` (the class in which you implemented the posted code).

So, `[self aBook]` is not valid.

Also, accept more answers.

Comment: ok!! i tried the line of code: aBook removeObjectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]; suggested by other developers, but still giving the same error!

Comment: its also giving warning "Book may not respond to removeobjectatindex". there must be mistake i have done, but i am not able to trace it.